# Lambda for compare function in c++ not working

Tags: c++, lambda

This code produces an error:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, [](int a, int b)->bool{return a>b;}> q;
```

Why?
(I know that for things like this I can just use `std::greater` or the default sorting, but I'm trying to learn how to create a custom comparator)

2 errors generated:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to object of type lambda
> error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
> ```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you add the exact error you've got, instead of just "I got an error".

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the type, but not the lambda expression itself as the template argument. And lambda should be specified as constructor argument.

E.g.

```
auto c = [](int a, int b)->bool{return a>b;}; // declare lambda in advance
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(c)> q(c);
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^      <- specify the type of lambda
//                                              ^ <- specify the lambda as constructor argument
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::function instead of lambda

```
auto q = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(const int&, const int&)>>{
            [](const int& a, const int& b)
            {
                return a < b;
            }
    };
```

Comment: How about using a plain function pointer instead? `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, bool (*)(int,int)> q([](int a, int b){ return a > b; });` Since the lambda is not capturing, and `std::function` has some overhead.